# How can I test a USB IR receiver to know which part is defective?

Tags: windows-10, usb, remote

I have two units of identical IR PC remotes. One used to work okay but now neither of them work. The batteries are good, The remote’s beam is seen in a camera so I guess its working. How can I test the USB receiver units to see whether they recognized are working?

FWIW, the remote has a keypad numbers. None of them shows in a notepad screen. So there’s no transmission to the PC. Can I know which part is defective? The remote or the receiver?

Comment: Please add OS tag. Under Linux, use `lsusb` and `dmesg` to verify they are recognized.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [USBPcap](https://desowin.org/usbpcap/).   [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), which can integrate with USBPcap and does much more, like network capturing.  These programs can capture and display data being transferred over the universal serial bus (USB).

At the very least, you should be able to determine if the IR receivers are receiving data with these programs.  You can do *a lot* more, at the cost of these programs complexity.

Comment: +1 for making me aware that WireShark is capable of capturing USB devices.

Comment: Given that the keypad numbers on the remote doesn't show in a notepad screen I guess there's no transmission and that it's a hardware problem. Is there still a point in using Wireshark?

Comment: @OMGsh did the kepad numbers work in notepad before?

Comment: @Keltari Everything was Okay, then after a while no key was identified, only once in a blue moon, I bought a new unit and also here nothing is identified. the battery has full voltage.